# Run C Code Block in Erlang

Tags: c, erlang

How to Run C Code Block from Erlang? ( Or Call a C function from erlang? )

Answer (score 22):

This is for creating a driver

Firstly you'll need to create the C/C++ files to do it.

They will need to include

```
#include "erl_driver.h"
#include "ei.h"
```

Then you'll need to set up the driver mapping

```
/* mapping of the drivers functions */
static ErlDrvEntry driver_entry = {
  NULL,                             /* init */
  startup_function_name,            /* startup  */
  shutdown_function_name,           /* shutdown */
  NULL,                             /* output */
  NULL,                             /* ready_input */
  NULL,                             /* ready_output */
  driver_name,                      /* the name of the driver */
  NULL,                             /* finish */
  NULL,                             /* handle */
  NULL,                             /* control */
  NULL,                             /* timeout */
  outputv_function_name,            /* outputv  */
  NULL,                             /* ready_async */
  NULL,                             /* flush */
  NULL,                             /* call */
  NULL,                             /* event */
  ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MARKER,          /* ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MARKER */
  ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION,   /* ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION */
  ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MAJOR_VERSION,   /* ERL_DRV_EXTENDED_MINOR_VERSION */
  ERL_DRV_FLAG_USE_PORT_LOCKING     /* ERL_DRV_FLAGs */
};

DRIVER_INIT(driver_name){
   return &driver_entry;
}
```

Note: if you are trying to run C++ code instead of C you'll need

```
extern "C" {
  DRIVER_INIT(driver_name){
    return &driver_entry;
  }
}
```

And you will need to cast any literal string with (char *)

Then it's good to define a struct that'll contain the port information

```
typedef struct
{
  ErlDrvPort port;
} port_data;
```

Lastly, you'll want to set up all the functions

```
static ErlDrvData startup_function_name(ErlDrvPort port, char *doc)
{
  /* Plus any other start up methods you need */
  port_data* d = (port_data*)driver_alloc(sizeof(port_data));
  d->port = port;
  return (ErlDrvData)d;
}

/* Plus any other shutdown methods you need */
static void shutdown_function_name(ErlDrvData handle)
{
  driver_free((char*)handle);
}

static void outputv_function_name(ErlDrvData handle, ErlIOVec *ev)
{
  port_data* d = (port_data*)handle;
  char* inputstring = ev->binv[1]->orig_bytes;
    ErlDrvTermData spec[] = {
      ERL_DRV_ATOM, driver_mk_atom("ok"),
      ERL_DRV_BUF2BINARY, inputstring, strlen(inputstring)
      ERL_DRV_TUPLE, 2
    };
    driver_send_term(d->port,driver_caller(d->port),spec,sizeof(spec)/sizeof(spec[0]));
}
```

You'll want to compile this C/C++ code into a shared object and link it with the erl interface

```
g++ -fpic -rdynamic -shared file_name -lerl_interface -lei
```

Now from erlang you'll want to do a couple things:
You'll need to load the driver

```
erl_ddll:load_driver("./location/of/driver", driver_name).
```

Then you'll open a port to the driver

```
Port = open_port({spawn, driver_name}, [binary]).
```

And lastly you can sent data to the port

```
port_command(Port, <<"String to Echo Back"),
receive
  {ok, String} -> io:format("Received ~p back from the driver")
end.
```

Answer (score 6):

The newest approach would consider NIFs http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html (be careful, it can crash VM). Regular way to do it involves linked in drivers (google up the link, because anti-spam holds it)

Comment: NIFs are something you probably want to avoid unless you *really* know what you are doing.  If you call into something that blocks, you've blown up Erlang's scheduler. If you call into something that crashes, your formerly robust Erlang is going to blow up.