# Care to expound on this statement made on Erlang performance?

Tags: image-processing, mapreduce, server, erlang, signal-processing

> There's something else to keep in mind: while Erlang does some things very well, it's technically still possible to get the same results from other languages. The opposite is also true; evaluate each problem as it needs to be, and choose the right tool according to the problem being addressed. **Erlang is no silver bullet and will be particularly bad at things like image and signal processing, operating system device drivers**, etc. and will shine at things like large software for server use (i.e.: queues, map-reduce), doing some lifting coupled with other languages, higher-level protocol implementation

I'm learning Erlang and this link (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/introduction#kool-aid) got me curious of the reasoning of good vs bad applications for Erlang. Can anyone expound on this statement?

Why do Erlang excel at some of the aformentioned fields and not in the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> while Erlang does some things very well, it's technically still possible to get the same results from other languages

Lets face it, really all programming languages can do more or less everything, and have ways to interface to C libraries to access anything they don't as such have a native library for.

The most obvious thing to point out is that all of Erlang boils down to C at the end of the day, and a little bit of assembler, but that's not really relevant to the point.

Thus it should be clear enough that anything you can write in Erlang could be written in C, and because you are eliminating a layer of abstraction and interpretation, if you do a reasonable job of it, it should be faster. Sometimes a little faster. Sometimes a lot faster.

> Erlang is no silver bullet and will be particularly bad at things like image and signal processing, operating system device drivers, etc.

This is the arena of nitty gritty byte and bit shifting magic, and if you introduce an abstraction layer for every bit you shift... you can easily end up degrading the best possible achievable performance by multiple orders of magnitude.

> and will shine at things like large software for server use (i.e.: queues, map-reduce), doing some lifting coupled with other languages, higher-level protocol implementation

This is the interesting bit. We've already established that if you write it in C, unless you do a sufficiently poor job of it, the result can only be better in terms of performance.

BUT performance isn't everything. In today’s world CPU and memory is cheap, but time to market is hugely important. A company might spend thousands on some extra hardware required to run your application because it's written in Erlang instead of C, but save (or make) millions because the product is first to market.

The fact is, if you match a given software problem to a high level language with the right paradigm, the average software engineer can often produce a given product many MANY times faster than if they had to write it in C.

Also, writing C is error prone, and provides vastly more scope for making mistakes and poor choices. That means a software engineer might write something in C badly enough that the equivalent Erlang, based on some very finely tuned mature clever C, if the Erlang itself is well through out, it might perform better!

> evaluate each problem as it needs to be, and choose the right tool according to the problem being addressed

Erlang is a really great tool, generally, but it does suit some problem domains more than others. There are some problems which might just be better solved with perl for example, or C, python, etc. When it fits the problem domain, Erlang can be unbeatable, but if it's a bad fit, it's definitely best to consider something else.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I had hoped for - this forums is made amazing by users like yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Both Erlang and C are Turing complete (except for the lack of infinite memory) and thus both can be used to compute anything if you don't care about absolute performance or the amount of memory or other system resources used.

In systems with constrained memory (tinyDuino, et.al.), the language runtime footprint (and OS resources required to support that runtime) may be a differentiator.  For problems where every multiply-accumulate per second counts (affects total cost in MegaWatt-days of power or microseconds of latency), any extra type or value checks, copies, or conversions, which might be implicit in the formal language definition, might incur an added performance cost in processor cycles, cache misses, or run-time memory management.  A C program might be specified without much of the above overhead for certain types of applications.  However, in applications which require such overhead for a robust solution, that performance advantage disappears as compared against the expected human cost of coding an equivalent (or more) robust solution.

Comment: Turing complete as in able to calculate everything that is calculable? How do we know that it can do that?

Comment: A common CS student exercise is to code up a Turing machine in various languages, thus proving the point.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang is a good solution when you want to create:

- **Realtime Systems:** They need predictable response time and Erlang *preemptive scheduling* and *per process garbage collection* features shine in it.
- **Distributed Systems:** Erlang has out of box mechanisms for distribution and a standard protocol which is called *Erlang Distributed Protocol*.
- **Fault Tolerant Systems:** The light-weight processes of Erlang which lets a process to crash without making other processes crash, and its mechanisms for processes to supervise and monitor each other is suitable for fault tolerant systems.
- **Concurrent Systems:** Although writing a concurrent system in languages like C and Java is possible, it can be hard and error prone. But Erlang has internal primitives that makes it so easy to write a concurrent program.

---

Erlang is not a good choice when you need to write a program that has to do **number crunching**, **image processing** and such things because your Erlang codes runs above some layers of abstraction. However there are official mechanisms in Erlang for taking the advantage of [C performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536459/erlang-c-and-erlang/34472633#34472633). Also [Hipe](https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/) (High Performance Erlang) project is worth considering.