# Is it possible to use Erlang and C language hybrid programming with C at high proportion?

Tags: c, erlang, elixir

My new work will use language Elixir.

I'm a fresh at this point also Erlang environment. With some research, I'm find the platform has some problem with performance for CPU intensive computing.

Does it possiable use C replace Erlang in above situation with `nif` even if C code maybe at high proportion? Or there are some limits that we can't do this.

Comment: See [Run C Code Block in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3525457/2402272).  I'm not sure whether that fully answers the question, however, because I'm having great difficulty interpreting the question's English.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry for my English.I have carefully update my question(maybe also has some problem).There has some mislead, you refers is Erlang able to use C. However, my problem focux on use C at high proportion.

Comment: That's a pretty subjective question. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note [the warning about long-running NIFs in the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#lengthy_work):

> As mentioned in the warning text at the beginning of this manual page, it is of **vital importance** that a native function returns relatively fast. It is difficult to give an exact maximum amount of time that a native function is allowed to work, but usually a well-behaving native function is to return to its caller within 1 millisecond. This can be achieved using different approaches. If you have full control over the code to execute in the native function, the best approach is to divide the work into multiple chunks of work and call the native function multiple times. This is, however, not always possible, for example when calling third-party libraries.
>
> The `enif_consume_timeslice()` function can be used to inform the runtime system about the length of the NIF call. It is typically always to be used unless the NIF executes very fast.

The documentation goes on to suggest three ways around this, "yielding NIF", "threaded NIF" and "dirty NIF".

Comment: this article is enough to have a good impression on `nif`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and safest way to run computationally intensive C code from Erlang is to write the C code as a standalone executable and connect it to Erlang through a port. See http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html for details.

Comment: It seems can able to avoid make EVM crash as `nif` .but,frankly, I think its not easy for me(I'm a newbie).BTW, should I create many ports of C programs or combine all of C code to one large file and expose one port(form illustrate scenario but the code part)?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a third way, You can run your c code as a stand alone Erlang node that communicates via the Erlang internode procotol.

See: http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html